# LINQ to SQL transaction and read ID of inserted record

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Can anybody explaoin me how to insert in database with Linq with transaction and read id of that record ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have a DBML setup, then add one to your project.
To add a DBML to your project from Solution Explorer:
`Right click on your project -> go to Add new Item -> select LINQ to SQL Classes`

To fill the DBML with your tables go to:
`View -> Server Explorer`
Expand your database and drag your tables onto the dbml viewer

Then if your table is caleld Widget:

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(myConnection);
db.Widgets.InsertOnSubmit(myWidget);

db.SubmitChanges();

//Here myWidget.Id will be set
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply commit your changes to the database. The newly inserted entity will have it's ID property automatically updated with the newly assigned id and you can read it from there.

Comment: Thanks, one more explanation pls. How to use transaction with linq  ?